# Node & Mongoose - Loading correct collection after clicking a link

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, collections, mongoose

I need help!! I have this code:

```
router.get("/campgrounds", function(req,res) {
    Campground.find({}, function(err, campgrounds) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("campgrounds/index", {campgrounds: campgrounds});
        }

    });
});
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find any good examples online.

I wanted index to load different mongo collections after clicking on the link that leads to /campgrounds which I want to change to /:locations_id.

The main page will have 3 links to location1, location2 and location3 respectively.

Is there a way to load a different collection (location 1, 2 or 3) at /:locations_id depending on the link clicked before?

My idea was to use req.params.locations_id and maybe append some info on the clicked link and use it in an if statement in order to load the correct collection.

Thank you very much for your help and I apologize for the extremely conceptual question.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I guess you can pull a trick.

```
//Put every collection in an array
var collections = [
  Campground,
  Collection2,
  Collection3
];

//When user visits: example.com/campgrounds/1
router.get("/campgrounds/:locationId", function(req,res) {
  //Parse the index from the URL
  var locId = parseInt(req.params.locationId);

  //Make sure that we aren't blown up :)
  if(isNaN(locId) || locId > 2) {
    //Default collection's index - which is Campground in this example
    locId = 0;
  }

  //Match the given collection by its index and return it
  collections[locId].find({}, function(err, campgrounds) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("campgrounds/index", {campgrounds: campgrounds});
    }
  });
});
```